# Using a temporary file in a bash shell script to test if a user inputted file exists (touch)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, touch

I'm working on a basic bash shell script, and I need to create a temporary file (I'm guessing using touch) to test if a file that is inputted by the user exists. So far what I have is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Ask user for filename
Read -p "Enter a filename" file

#See if file exists
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
   echo "$file found"
else
   echo "$file not found"
fi
```

I know this will be able to tell me if the file is there or not, but I'm really new to shell scripting and cannot figure out how I could actually test to make sure this is true with a temporary file. I've read about touch which makes a temporary file, but how can I use it to see if there is another file with the name they input?
Thanks in advance

Comment: touch command just changes the timestamp of file. It creates an empty file if the file doesn't exist. But if the file exists it changes the timestamp of the file.

Answer (score 1):

`touch` just creates a *named* file; there's really no such thing as a temporary file, outside of how long you plan to keep it.

What you are looking for is the `mktemp` command, which creates a guaranteed new file and outputs that file's name in one step; this prevents
an adversary from intercepting the name you *intend* to use and creating it either before (or after) you check to see if it exists.

```
file=$(mktemp)

echo "File $file ready for use"
```

`mktemp` takes an optional argument that it will use as a template for the name of the file it creates. Each trailing `X` in the template is replaced with a "random" character, so if the template contains no `X`s, then the template is used as-is as the name of the file to create. If `mktemp` fails to create a *new* file, it will have a non-zero exit status.

```
$ mktemp foo || echo "Failed to create foo"
foo
$ ls foo
foo
$ mktemp foo || echo "Failed to create foo"
mktemp: mkstemp failed on foo: File exists
Failed to create foo
```